# How to make selection move through variable data in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, do-loops

I am trying to continue the process until the end of the cells, but the selection needs to change in a set order. Here's the code:

```
' C_P Macro
' copies from worksheet & pastes in new sheet
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L

  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim Look As String
  Dim iRow As Integer
  With Windows("Audubon-Crest-Rent-Roll-201502-1.xlsx").Activate
  Set rng1 = Range("A:A")
  ActiveCell = Range("A228")
  Do
    Windows("Audubon-Crest-Rent-Roll-201502-1.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A228:A239").Select
        Selection.Copy
    Windows("Audubon Crest Rent Roll 20150219-altered.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B17").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Windows("Audubon-Crest-Rent-Roll-201502-1.xlsx").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A228:A239").Offset(13, 0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Audubon Crest Rent Roll 20150219-altered.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B17").Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("B18").Select
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1))
End With
End Sub
```

**As** you can see, what it basically does is Make a selection of 11 rows and then transpose copies the data into the next workbook at the next row. I F8'd through the procedure and I can tell that it works well for one selection then moves down 13 rows and does the next selection, BUT I'm not sure how to make it continuously move through the data. I need for it to always select 11 rows, do the procedure then count thirteen rows down and do it again until it hits an empty row. Ideally I could set it up to Find a certain cell entry and select 11 rows once it locates the next instance of this cell entry, but I think the 13 rows remains as a pattern so if it just counts down 13 rows that should be fine.

So, I think my quandary is how to make the row selections variable. When I look into the code I can see that my row selections are concrete values so if I were to run the Macro it wouldn't move down, it would just do the cells I have indicated. How can I make it move down through the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to activate a workbook to do something with a range in it, rather you can do something with a range in a non-active workbook by qualifying what workbook the range is in first. The same applies to worksheets and ranges. Admittedly that is not what is causing problems in the code-sample you are posting, since you're really not touching on that, but it is making your code a lot harder to read.

One possible solution to your problem is a macro looking something like this:

```
Sub Copy_Paste
    Dim sourceBook As Workbook, destBook As Workbook, sourceRange As Range, destRange As Range

    Set sourceBook = Workbooks("Audubon-Crest-Rent-Roll-201502-1.xlsx")
    Set destBook = Workbooks("Audubon Crest Rent Roll 20150219-altered.xlsm")

    Set sourceRange = sourceBook.Worksheets(<name of sheet the data is in as string>).Range("A228:A239")
    Set destRange = destBook.Worksheets(<name of sheet the data shall be copied to as string>).Range("B17")

    Do
        sourceRange.Copy
        destRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Set destRange = destRange.Offset(1, 0)
        Set sourceRange = sourceRange.Offset(13, 0)
    Loop Until IsEmpty(sourceRange)
End Sub
```

As you can see I define the ranges which shall be copied, by naming them and then telling Excel where they are by using the `Set` statement. For each iteration of the loop I then move the destination range one row further down by setting it again, and letting it be *offset* by one row from the previous destination range, by using the [Offset-property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx). I do the same with the source-range, but I am offsetting it by 13 rows, as that was what it looked like you were doing in your code-sample.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, your code is 10x cleaner than mine. I appreciate the help. I am getting a 438 error on   

Set sourceRange = sourceBook.Worksheets(<name of sheet the data is in as string>).Range("A228:A239")

Any idea why?

Comment: @IvanW Yeah, you need to put in the actual names of the sheets in the parantheses where "<name of sheet the data is in as string>" and "<name of sheet the data shall be copied to as string>" are. That said, I haven't actually tested the code, so you may have to make other modifications to it too, in order to get it to work.

Comment: LOL. Yea I put in the names. Thanks for all your help though. Your code is tremendously cleaner. I just need to workout the "Object doesn't support this property" issue with the Set statement. Thanks, I'll work through it. You got me 90% there!

Comment: Are you certain the workbook and worksheet-names are correct, and that both workbooks are open? Setting the ranges seems to work fine for me with the syntax looking something like `Set sourceRange = sourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A228:A239")` @IvanW

Comment: I just solved it by working with the intellisense dialog box, I wasn't putting the names in quotes and parenthesis. I was doing Worksheets.Sheet1.Range - That is incorrect. Thanks a BUNCH!!!